# How do I hook up this light fixture?

Tags: wiring, lighting, light-fixture

I had drywall work done recently, and the contractor said I just need to connect the black ceiling wires to the black lighting wire and the white ceiling wires with the white lighting wire. I did this, and the light turns on, but I cannot turn it off with the pull switch it is attached to. Am I missing something here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that the pull switch is broken?  Is there a second light connected to the second set of wires?

Comment: @crip659 No second light connected to the switch. It's possible that the switch broke during the drywall work, but I don't have a continuity tester of any kind on hand.

Comment: You should have a second light or an outlet being powered from that box.  You have one cable for power in, a second cable for the switch loop.  The third cable powers something else from that switch.

Comment: Is there a wall switch that might control the light too. There's the makings of a switch loop.

Comment: That's really weird.  You've got 3 pairs of wire and a black and white nutted together.